# How can I give remote access to my visualsvn server

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008-r2, visualsvn-server, windows-server

I am currently running VisualSVN Server Enterprise on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 machine and I had no problem installing and setting it up locally. I need to give remote access to a user in the UK and wanted to know how this is done on a Windows Server. I presume he will access it using https but I have no idea what I need to do on my end locally to grant remote access. Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work? Or do you need additional help?

Answer (score 11):

First can you please check the Visual SVN on what port and IP it's listening:

To do so, go to 
Start > VisualSVN server manager > Right click on VisualSVN Server (local) > Properties

Check the Network, Servername should be the **public ip address** of the server.

You can find your public IP on www.whatsmyip.org

When you change it try the server ip and the Port, if it works.

for example: 
https://YourPublicIP:YourPort/svn/

Usualy the VisualSVN takes port: 8443 and keeps the 443 for IIS.

If you cant connect to your public IP and SVN best thing to do is check your Firewall settings.

**Does your server has Firewall before it? If yes open the port that VisualSVN uses?**
**Does your windows 2008 Firewall bypass this port?**

How to change Firewall settings on windows 2008: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/configure-Windows-Server-2008-advanced-firewall-MMC-snap-in.html

Comment: Currently the way my network is setup I have 2 gigabit ethernet cards on my server. Only one is enabled and active and for the lan side which is connected to my switch and my isp's router is connected to the switch. Does that mean I have to enable the second card and put my public ip on that interface?

Comment: How do you connect to this Machine? Is there any public connection between the lan side and the windows server?

If you go on the server and you check the public IP and then try from outside the network to reach it would you be able to see it?

If yes then no need to open any other side connections just enable the IP on VisualSVN.

Comment: Wait Wait!... Your talking about a router right? Just go in the Router add the rule for the SSL port that Visual SVN is using and point it to the Windows 2008 server internal IP.

Then anything that comes to your external IP with port 8445 for example will be redirected to the Windows server.

Comment: So I don't need to activate the second network interface with my public ip just put a rule on the router to point to my server's lan ip right? Currently the visualsvn port is on 443 do I need to change that to 8443?

Comment: No you dont, if your not using IIS SSL on the server you can use 443 for VisualSVN, so on the router make a rule for port 443 to redirect to your Windows server 2008, Please check if you have the Server with static IP (internal static IP) and not automatic.

Comment: Yes I do have a static lan IP configured on the active network interface. Do I need to change the server name to my public ip on the visualsvn settings?

Comment: Could you get the Server listen to your public IP?

Comment: One question if I Have to change the visualsvn settings to my public  ip my local guys can't access the server so how do I set it up so I can do both. Access locally and the external access?

Comment: to resolve this solution in my case i created a header in place of an IP:

On locale comptures i used in host file:
Locat server ip     www.svn.local

And on the remote ips
your ip     www.svn.local

Comment: or if you dont mind you can add it on subdomain on ur domain live domain i mean.