# VisualSVN Server over HTTP on LAN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I installed visualSVN server on Windows 7. I used port forwarding option on D-Link router. I am using 443 port. However, I am still unable to access/browse svn over HTTP. I also disabled firewall to check. I am still unable to communicate with VisualSVN server over HTTP.

Is there any help?

Comment: Is this on a local machine or a remote one?

Comment: I have install Visual SVN server on my desktop computer. Both computers are on the same network. I can't access the Desktop computer (with visual svn server) over http

Comment: Try the suggestion posted here (you may have to modify it slightly): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10513572/866930

Comment: I already tried it. But, its not working

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, VisualSVN Server does not require any specific configuration to be accessible from WAN or LAN. You need to setup your network environment (i.e. hardware and software configuration) as for any other network service (e.g. a web or an FTP server) that you want to make accessible from WAN or LAN. Exact actions depend on your network environment.

- You have to specify error message that you get on client. I guess that the issue is not related to port-forwarding, but to your DNS settings. What URL do you use to access the VisualSVN Server? Have you tried to use IP address in URL instead of a hostname?
- If the client and server machine are located on the same network, then why do you need to setup port-forwarding? In most cases, you don't need this unless you want to access the server from the Internet (over WAN).
- You've specified that that you enabled port-forwarding of port 443 to VisualSVN Server machine. You tell that you want to access VisualSVN Server via HTTP. HTTP uses port 80, by default. Make sure that your settings are right: you have to setup port-forwarding on the same port VisualSVN Server is binded to.